# Sew button/object to cloth simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

How do I put a button or pin an object into a cloth simulation? I'm trying to create a clothing that needs many buttons but I don't know how to do that(sew the buttons to the cloth).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your button object, shift select your cloth object, switch to *Edi*t mode, select 3 vertices of your cloth (or one vertex), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*, the button will follow the cloth when the simulation will happen:

[image]

Comment: it works. thanks